Best interesting chess engine?
I've been wanting to use a chess engine for analysis to push myself to the next level as I'm coming back from a long chess hiatus. I have tried using Stockfish, but I want a chess engine with nasty moves that thinks out of the box. My first instinct was to use Lc0, but I've heard that it doesn't provide the best performance for my system. My specs: i5 14600KF, Rx 7600, 16 gigs of ddr5 ram.
Edit: I'm also fine with any outside of the box chess engine. Doesn't matter the elo or the gpu usage, just trying to surprise my opponents and take them out of their prep.

What is an "interesting" chess engine?

You can surprise opponents with any engine - just run the engine in multi-PV mode and focus on the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc. moves that the engine suggests.
You can also try running Lc0 with high WDL contempt.
Warning: these 2nd, 3rd, etc. moves are not the first recommended move for a reason. If you play them, you'll be playing inferior chess with the hope that your opponent makes misplays that compensate.

+1 for mention and link on high WDL contempt.

I should say that you should analyze your games yourself to actually have serious improvement (and it is a good idea to analyze your own games).
That being said, there are adaptive chess engines that play surprising, but not best/good moves. Also, you can play against adaptive chess engines in chess.com (link) or adaptive bots at lichess (examples: one,two). Other than adaptive engines, some other chess.com engines that are probably usable for your purpose include Wendy, Jonas, Olga, Maria, David
Also see these 2 answers: one, two.
